# $\mu$-strongly convex is strictly convex

Tags: convex-analysis

From this definition, how to prove $\mu$-strongly convex is strictly convex? I know there are some similar questions in the website, but they use the definition containing differentiable. But that is not necessary.

The defition of $\mu$-strongly convex is:

f is $\mu$-strongly convex on T (with respect to the Euclidean norm $||\cdot ||$) if there exists a $\mu$ > 0 such
that for any $\theta, \tau \in X$ and $\lambda \in [0, 1]$ we have

$$f(\lambda \theta + (1-\lambda) \tau) \leq \lambda f(\theta) + (1-\lambda) f(\tau) + \mu \lambda (1-\lambda) || \theta - \tau||^2$$

I know if I can drop the last term above, then it is done. But how to justify this drop step? From the definition, it only says there exists a $\mu$, it doesn't say any $\mu >0$, so I cannot say let $\mu \to 0$ and drop the last term.

Comment: I think you have a sign wrong in the definition; compare with e.g. [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convex_function#Strongly_convex_functions). In particular, $\mu$-strong convexity should imply $\mu'$-strong convexity for $0 < \mu' < \mu$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Arun G is correct: the correct definition of strongly convex is

> *Definiton.* A function $f \colon (X, \| \cdot \|) \to \mathbb R$ is $m$-strongly convex if there exists a $m > 0$ such that
> $$
> f\big( (1 - t) x + t y \big)
> \le (1 - t) f(x) + t f(y) - \frac{1}{2} m t (1 - t) \| x - y \|^2
> \qquad \forall x, y \in X \ \forall t \in (0, 1).
> $$

(Note that the inequality is always an equality for $t \in \{ 0, 1 \}$, so we can restrict ourselves to $t \in (0, 1)$.

Now let $x, y \in X$ with $x \ne y$ and $t \in (0, 1)$.
If $f$ is $m$-strongly convex for some $m > 0$, then
$$
f\big( (1 - t) x + t y \big)
\le (1 - t) f(x) + t f(y) - \frac{1}{2} m t (1 - t) \| x - y \|^2.
$$
Since $x \ne y$, we have $\| x - y \| > 0$ and thus (since $m, t, 1 - t > 0$)
$$
f\big( (1 - t) x + t y \big)
< (1 - t) f(x) + t f(y),
$$
that is, $f$ is strictly convex.